# Grep exclude folder and search using linux

Tags: linux, grep

grep command

if I am in

```
/var/
```

I want to search `/var/www`

recursively

but not

```
/var/www/exclude
```

Comment: Is this haiku? :)

Answer (score 7):

You can also use grep -v "/foldername/". -v takes away all matches.

```
grep -r string /var/www/ | grep -v "/exclude/"
```

Comment: okay, I understand exclude, but I am already in /var/ folder, do I really have to write /var/www/.  I want to just write /www

Comment: The safest way if you are using this method is to use it like: grep -r string $(pwd) | grep -v ^/var/www/exclude/

Answer (score 0):

Use `--exclude=*.log*`
to skip files containing the word 'log'.

Comment: there should be star after equal sign . When posted, it removed it.

Comment: enclose with a \` what you don't want to be formatted, e.g. `--exclude=*.log`

Answer (score -1):

The option `--exclude-dir=exclude` might work.

It has some limitations, though : it will ignore all "exclude" folders, not just `/var/www/exclude`.

```
grep -r --exclude-dir=exclude pattern /var/www/
```

if you're already in var, then you can of course just use www :

```
grep -r --exclude-dir=exclude pattern www/
```

Answer (score -1):

1) Use `grep -R -f file.txt`, where in `file.txt` you list all the file and directory names, except /var/www/exclude

2) use the following bash script:

```
 for i in $( ls /var/www/ ); do
   if [ "$i" != "/var/www/exclude" ] ; then
      grep -R "my search term" $i
   fi
 done
```